# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-9

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[PMURP_Func_ParseArray] (@Array VARCHAR(1000),@separator CHAR(1))
RETURNS @T Table (ExtractWords varchar(50))
AS 
BEGIN
--DECLARE @T Table (col1 varchar(50))
-- @Array is the array we wish to parse
-- @Separator is the separator charactor such as a comma
DECLARE @separator_position INT -- This is used to locate each separator character
DECLARE @array_value VARCHAR(1000) -- this holds each array value as it is returned
-- For my loop to work I need an extra separator at the end. I always look to the
-- left of the separator character for each array value

SET @array = @array + @separator

-- Loop through the string searching for separtor characters
WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%', @array) <> 0 
BEGIN
-- patindex matches the a pattern against a string
SELECT @separator_position = PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%',@array)
SELECT @array_value = LEFT(@array, @separator_position - 1)
-- This is where you process the values passed.
INSERT into @T VALUES (@array_value) 
-- Replace this select statement with your processing
-- @array_value holds the value of this element of the array
-- This replaces what we just processed with and empty string
SELECT @array = STUFF(@array, 1, @separator_position, '')
END
RETURN 
END
```

and

```
Select Description from Bad_Names WHERE Description in (Select * from dbo.PMURP_Func_ParseArray('bala',' '))
```

and

```
Description,Name_ID
PK_BadNames nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY    Description
```

Comment: jquery version is 1.8.3

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? $.data has changed to $._data

Comment: So i'd say use $._data. And sorry i deleted comment by error so now my question is below your answer... :=) The error you get means validator is undefined. Anyway, the $._data or $.data is not a method publicly supported...

Comment: Changed $.data to $._data but still am getting the same error

Comment: Try by upgrading your plugin/jquery or use jquery migrate

Comment: I don't know, do some tests on your side

Comment: ok another thing is am getting this error in IE9 only..it is working fine in IE10

Comment: `.validate()` is the _initialization_ method and it's typically called once on DOM ready, not on the button click.  The click is automatically captured and handled by the plugin.

Comment: Why did you edit your question so drastically? The latest edit completely changes the question that's being asked. Also, the edit isn't even a question. I came here from Google and was really confused between the question title and text. The answers helped my problem, but they are referring to the original question.

Answer (score 8):

In my situation, I have a `<form></form>` inside a `<form></form>` which causing this error.

Answer (score 2):

My issue with this error was related to Tuyen Nguyen answer --one form tag inside another form tag.

While using a Bootstrap modal dialog div-- a container for a partial view for  a form--

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

I incorrectly  placed the modal-container div in a @using Html.BeginForm statements tags which was causing the Script 5007 error.

Placing it outside the braces of Html.BeginForm makes the error go away

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

We got this error when we tried to call validate() on an element that *wasn't* the actual form element.  Ex:  `$('div#entryForm').validate()`

When we changed the jQuery selector to select the root form element, we had no problems:

```
$('form#form1').validate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using Knockout js?

I know its an old post, but first result in Google when I searched.  So, in case this might help someone else... for me it was calling the $(form).validate() prior to applying the knockout bindings.

I had the validate call in with the form I was loading for a dialog box, so it was running on load and then knockout model was being applied.  I moved the validate call into a dialogReady function and then called it after knockout - problem solved.